# Android : going back to the main activity Onbackkeypressed from login activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a problem when i press the back button on my login activity it takes me back to the main activity (after the user logs out from main activity)

I have tried ..

`intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);`

Please help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you call your MainActivity's `finish()` after starting the login activity

Comment: Any how there was a small mistake i did .. i forgot to put `finish()` at one place . so accepting the answer .thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To help you, you should provide us some code. But after taking a look on the description of your problem, your are probably starting a new activity after the users log out. Thenm when the user click the back button, he comes back to the previous activity.

Comment: after the user logs out i am starting the login activity. do i have some other option ?

Comment: So, what's your goal when the user press the back button. The back button will call the finish() method and this will close your current activity and open the last one. If you would like to avoid the user is opening the last activity, call finish() before oppening the new one, so this "last" activity will be deleted from the queue.

Comment: if on login activity he presses back key  then the application should minimize or close .so i was implementing `moveTaskToBack(true);` , but that didn't worked either

Comment: Is the logout option present everywere in the app or only in one activity?

Answer (score 0):

What about overriding the [onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) method and handling the desired "action/intent" by yourself?

Comment: I think that this is a bad idea. Android is respecting a certain activity life cycle. It is better to finish the desired activity before opening the new one if the user's goal is not to come back to this activity.

Comment: That's absolutely true. But as stated above he already tried that so lets hope for a clarification why this "finish() call" didn't worked or what a behaviour is desired.